# React Toolkit Query. Dispatch works incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

Inside the "for" loop "getKeys" function should create POST request and in the response it should update "encryptedKeys" state. But the state in slice is overwriting with new values and the old one is disappearing from the state.

```
function DragDrop() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const files = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.file.uplaodedFiles;
  });
  const encryptedKeys = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.file.encryptedKeys;
  });
  const [createEncryptionKey, results] = useCreateEncryptionKeyMutation();

  const getKeys = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await createEncryptionKey(data).unwrap();
      if (data) {
        dispatch(setEncryptedKeys([...encryptedKeys, data]));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (file) => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
      getKeys();
      const data = {
        file: file[i],
      };
      arr.push(data);
    }
    dispatch(setUplaodedFiles([...files, ...arr]));
  };
```

API

```
const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "file",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://...",
  }),
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      createEncryptionKey: builder.mutation({
        query: (data) => {
          return {
            method: "POST",
            url: "/key",
            body: {
              key: data.key,
            },
          };
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});
```

If I upload 3 files, only one will be in "encryptedKeys" state but acctually 3 files should be there.

Comment: Please [edit] to include all relevant code you are working with, e.g. the Redux code, so we can see how the `setEncryptedKeys` action is processed. See [mcve]. Note that `encryptedKeys` is a stale closure over whatever it was when it was selected from state prior to `handleChange` being called. In all likelihood you should probably be updating the Redux store from the `createEncryptionKey` endpoint if you are wanting to persist the values.

Comment: You're calling an async function inside your loop without awaiting it.

Comment: @DrewReese setEncryptedKeys was added

Comment: @Derek how can I await it?

Comment: What is `createEncryptionKey` and its return value even used for? Where did you [edit] and add `setEncryptedKeys`? What is `data` that is passed to `createEncryptionKey` now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're encountering an issue where only one encrypted key is being stored in the 'encryptedKeys' state when you expect all three files to be there. The problem stems from the asynchronous nature of the getKeys function inside your loop. Since getKeys is an asynchronous function, by the time the response is received and dispatch is called to update the state, the loop has already continued to the next iteration. This results in only one key being added to the state.

Comment: Yes, I understand that ‘for’ loop ends earlier then the first ‘getKey’ request gets the response but how  can I fix it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in async requests inside the 'for' loop, to fix it the
'handleChange()' function was updated to this one

```js
  const handleChange = (file) => {
    document.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = "";
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
      const { publicKeyPEM, privateKeyPEM } = createKeys();
      createEncryptionKey({
        token,
        key: publicKeyPEM,
      })
        .unwrap()
        .then((res) => {
          const keys = decryptKeys(res, privateKeyPEM);
          const data = {
            file: file[i],
            forge: keys,
          };
          arr.push(data);
          dispatch(setUplaodedFiles([...files, ...arr]));
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };
```

Thanks @hussain @derek